# What's the best way to apply a function to all the outputs of tf.split?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to write my own convolutional neural network, but as to how to apply the kernel to the input I am struggling.

My initial idea was as follows (psedocode ahead):

```
a, b, c, d... = tf.split(value, num_or_size_splits=x, 0)
kernel(a)
kernel(b)
kernel(c)
kernel(d)
...
```

Obviously having to list it out like that doesn't seem right to me. I also don't like the fact that tf.split doesn't return 1 thing as some kind of list you can do operations on.

What's the best way to do this? I want an efficient way to apply a function to all the outputs of tf.split.

Comment: Can you provide more details about "tf.split doesn't return 1 thing as some kind of list you can do operations on"? To my knowledge, if you don't unpack, `tf.split` will return a list of tensors.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. If I try the following code:

    import tensorflow as tf

    sess = tf.Session()

    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], name='a')

    #dirt, hirt = tf.split(a, [2,4], axis=0) 

    dirt = tf.split(a, [2,4], axis=0) 

    dirt = tf.Print(dirt, [dirt, "."], summarize=9999)

    print(sess.run(dirt))


It has a problem. If you uncomment out the dirt hirt line and comment out the dirt line its fine. It doesn't like putting everything into a list. I want the outputs put into 1 variable. Damn no space for more explanations lol

Comment: If you need more space, you can edit your question with updates/explanations. I don't quite understand "I want the outputs put into 1 variable". If you are talking about `tf.Variable`, why do you split the tensor in the first place?

Comment: Something like x = [kernel(x) for  x in tf.split(...)] ?